Python (pyparsing): parsing legacy curly braces file format
I have to parse with Python (pyparse) a legacy file format that is not well defined.
It is of the curly brace family (im fact, having to parse arbitrary curly brace formats is a recurring issue because people are always like "XML is too verbose, let's invent our own format").
So I have things like
Variable = [1, 2]
Variable2 = {
   Variable,
   "Literal",
}

Variable[1] = Variable2

Namespace::Function(argument, {"string literal",
100})

Newlines are significant outside of expressions (separating statements like ; does in C) but not significant in any kind of braces ({}, () and []).
To make sense of it, it needs to be parsed such that:

Each line is a child of the root of the AST (where "line" refers to lines delimited by line breaks not inside any kind of braces).
Each kind of parentheses constitutes a node (annotated with the type of parentheses).
The children of a parenthesis list are comma separated (in this sense newlines also constitute a kind of brace).
Anything else is treated as a single token to be handled in another pass.

So for the above example the AST should look like this:
Root
 * Brace: \n
   * Token: 'Variable ='
   * Brace: []
     * Token: '1'
     * Token: '2'
 * Brace: \n
   * Token: 'Variable2 ='
   * Brace: {}
     * Token: 'Variable'
     * Token: '"Literal"'
 * Brace: \n
   * Token: 'Variable'
   * Brace: []
     * Token: '1'
   * Token: '= Variable2'
 * Brace: \n
   * Token: 'Namespace:Function'
     * Brace: ()
       * Token: 'argument'
       * Brace: {}
         * Token: '"string literal"'
         * Token: '100'

Represented in Python as something like:
[
  Brace('\n', [
    'Variable =',
    Brace('[]', ['1', '2'])
  ]),
  ...

The issues are

Specifying the syntax for the parser,
Converting the result from the parser into a data structure that I can use afterwards.

(I used a dedicated parser package that did (1), but the result was (2) completely unusable for any further steps, so I'm trying again, this time with pyparsing.)

What specifically is your question?

Parsing Curly Basic Formats with 'pyparsing':

Define The Grammer: Use pyparsing to create rules for handling variables, literals, different types of brackets ('[]','{}','()'). Use nestedExpr for nested structures.

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, nums, nestedExpr, quotedString, Group, ZeroOrMore, LineEnd

identifier = Word(alphas + "_", alphas + nums + "_")
literal = quotedString

square_braces = nestedExpr('[', ']', content=identifier | literal)
curly_braces = nestedExpr('{', '}', content=identifier | literal | square_braces)
parentheses = nestedExpr('(', ')', content=identifier | curly_braces)

statement = Group(identifier + '=' + (square_braces | curly_braces | parentheses))
grammar = ZeroOrMore(statement + LineEnd().suppress())


Convert To AST: Use parse actions to build an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). Define a Brace class to represent a different brace types.

class Brace:
    def __init__(self, brace_type, children):
        self.brace_type = brace_type
        self.children = children

def create_ast_node(tokens):
    return Brace(tokens[0], tokens[1:])

statement.setParseAction(create_ast_node)


Example Usage:

Parse your input and generate as AST
input_text = """
Variable = [1, 2]
Variable2 = {
   Variable,
   "Literal",
}
"""
result = grammar.parseString(input_text)
print(result)

This approach efficiently parses custom brace formats and organizes the output into a structured, usable form. I hope my definition helps!
